# type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Null' in get method flutter " code flutter "

Tags: string, flutter, compiler-errors

I'm having this error and I can't resolve it, as soon as I read my qr code, the display page is giving this string error, follow the code to try to help.

```
class UserTela extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserTelaState createState() => _UserTelaState();

  final String code;
  const UserTela({super.key, required this.code});
}

class _UserTelaState extends State<UserTela> {
  String? _selected;
  List<Map> _myJson = [
    {'id': '1', 'image': 'assets/icons/brasil.png', 'name': 'PT-BR'},
    {'id': '2', 'image': 'assets/icons/germany.png', 'name': 'DE'},
    {'id': '3', 'image': 'assets/icons/ukunited.png', 'name': 'US'}
  ];

  get code => null;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

```
Text(
                  code,
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    letterSpacing: 1,
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NU0g.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ax2rD.png)

I sent the messages above with the errors pointed out

Comment: Welcome! Can you [please read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732) about the problems with images of text and then edit your question to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1):

you can just do like this , no need of `get code => null`; if you just need to display code.

```
Text(widget.code,
       style: TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
               color: Colors.black87,
                    letterSpacing: 1,
                  ),
                ),
```